# No call to JavaScript function submitting form in Angular and PHP

Tags: php, angularjs

There in nothing happen while I'm submitting the form, actually no call to the JavaScript function. Don't know why. I'm new to this.

My HTML page:

```
<html>  
  <head>  
       <title>Clear Data</title>  
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>  
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
  </head>  
  <body>  
       <br /><br />  
       <div class="container" style="width:600px;">  
            <h3 align="center">Select Store</h3>  
            <br />  
            <div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="usercontroller" ng-init="loadCountry()">  
                 <select name="country" ng-model="country" class="form-control" ng-change="loadState()">  
                      <option value="">Select Store</option>  
                      <option ng-repeat="country in countries" value="Id">{{country.store_name}}  (Store Id:{{country.id}})</option>  
                 </select>  
                 <br />
                 <div id="form" ng-if="country.includes('Id')">
                 <h4 align="center">Enter Date Range</h4> <br/>
                 <form  ng-submit="submit_form()">
                     <input type="hidden" name="Storeid" value="{{country.id}}">
                   From Date:<input type="text" name="fromDate" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ttt" required/>
                   To Date:<input type="text"  name="toDate" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ttt" required/><br>
                   <br><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                 </form> </div>
                 <br />     
            </div>
            </div> 
       </div>  
  </body>
```

My JavaScript code is:

```
<script>  
 var app = angular.module("myapp",[]);  
 app.controller("usercontroller", function($scope, $http){  
  $scope.loadCountry = function(){  
       $http.get("loadStore.php")  
       .success(function(data){  
            $scope.countries = data;  
       })  
  }
  $scope.submit_form = function (){
    $http({
      method  : 'POST',
      url     : 'clearallData.php',
      storeid    : this.Storeid, //forms user object
      fromdate : this.fromDate,
      todate : this.toDate 
     })
     .success(function(data) {
        $scope.message = data.message;
      });
        }
     });  
  </script>
```

Comment: Your code is correct, check the console once if there any errors.

Comment: @VenkatLokeswar no error dude

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Clear Data</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
<br /><br />
<div class="container" style="width:600px;">
    <h3 align="center">Select Store</h3>
    <br />
    <div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="usercontroller" ng-init="loadCountry()">


       <!-- I change here, because select has ngOptions in angular , so you dont use ng-repeat-->
        <select ng-change="loadState(name.id)" ng-model="name" name="name" id="name" class="form-control"
                ng-options="country as country.name for country in countries track by country.id" >
            <option disabled="disabled" value="">Select Country</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <div id="form" ng-show="country_status">
            <h4 align="center">Enter Date Range</h4> <br/>

            <!-- Pay Attention here -->

            <form  ng-submit="submit_form()">
                <input type="hidden" name="Storeid" value="{{ countryId }}">
                From Date:<input type="text" name="fromDate" ng-model="fromDate" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ttt" required/>
                To Date:<input type="text"  name="toDate" ng-model="toDate" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ttt" required/><br>
                <br><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>

            <!-- Pay Attention here stop -->


        </div>
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
    var app = angular.module("myapp",[]);
    app.controller("usercontroller", function($scope, $http){
        $scope.country_status = false;
        $scope.loadCountry = function(){
            $http.get("loadStore.php")
                .success(function(data){
                    $scope.countries = data;
                })
          /*  $scope.countries = [{
                'id':1,
                'name': 'india1'
            },{
                'id':2,
                'name': 'india2'
            }]*/
        };
        $scope.submit_form = function (){
            console.log('Hello ', $scope.countryId,$scope.fromDate, $scope.toDate);
//My scope display here, if yours is not please copy and paste this code in your project directory and test it.
            return $http({
                method  : 'POST',
                url     : 'clearallData.php',
                data: {
                    storeid : $scope.countryId, //forms user object
                    fromdate: $scope.fromDate,
                    todate  : $scope.toDate
                }
            }).then(function(response) {
                $scope.message = response.data.message;
            });
        };
        $scope.loadState = function (countrySelected) {
            console.log('countrySelected', countrySelected);
            $scope.country_status = true;
            $scope.countryId = countrySelected;
            console.log('$scope.countryId', $scope.countryId);
        }
    });


</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Still no change, while using 
alert($scope.fromDate);
its says undefined

Comment: this work perfectly on my machine. Al u need do is to copy the script to the base of the html. I mean make sure you angular js load first.

Comment: I have copied you all code and run it on machine,still no error and no call to the php page nad nothing on alert

Comment: use the console.log to check , console.log('To date ', $scope.toDate, $scope.fromDate);  Then open the chrome developer console using ctrl+shift+i, to inspect the output

Comment: it work perfectly on my machine, i would love to share the screen shot but no space to paste that here

Comment: I also want to share an image but cant

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things wrong with your code.

First, you're not actually sending any data with your POST request. Second, you ought to use $scope instead of `this` to access your data (well, at least as long as you're not using the recommended *controllerAs*-syntax). Third, `success` is deprecated. Use promises instead.

All of that comes down to the following changes:

```
$scope.submit_form = function (){
    return $http({
        method  : 'POST',
        url     : 'clearallData.php',
        data: {
            storeid : $scope.Storeid, //forms user object
            fromdate: $scope.fromDate,
            todate  : $scope.toDate
        }   
    }).then(function(response) {
        $scope.message = response.data.message;
    });
}
```

and in the view change this:

```
From Date:<input type="text" name="fromDate" ng-model="fromDate" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ttt" required/>
To Date:<input type="text" name="toDate" ng-model="toDate" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ttt" required/><br>
```

Whether this will actually fix your issue, I cannot say, since you havn't provided any error messages or similar information that might suggest what actually goes wrong.

Comment: Still no change, while using 
alert($scope.fromDate);
its says undefined

Comment: You're certain you've added `ng-model` to your inputs in the view as well? Do you get any error messages in the browser console?

Comment: I have added `ng-model` in views and console there is no error

Comment: In your `<select>`-tag you use a `ng-change`-directive, but the function it references isn't shown in the controller. Have you perhaps forgotten to add `$scope.loadState = function(){ .. }` to your controller?